# Compile SASS with webpack into multiple CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, webpack-4

Consider a webpack 4 built project with the following structure that has ./blocks/index.js as the main entry point:

```sh
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── editor.blocks.css
│   │   ├── style.blocks.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── editor.blocks.js
├── blocks
│   ├── block1
│   │   ├── editor.scss
│   │   ├── style.scss
│   │   ├── index.js
│   ├── block2
│   │   ├── editor.scss
│   │   ├── style.scss
│   │   ├── index.js
│   ├── block3
│   │   ├── editor.scss
│   │   ├── style.scss
│   │   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js
```

The SASS files are imported into the `index.js` file inside each block folder.

When webpack runs it should:

- Concatenate and compile all `style.scss` files to `./assets/css/style.blocks.css`.
- Concatenate and compile all `editor.scss` files to `./assets/css/editor.blocks.css`.

At the moment, it kind of works but instead of concatenating and compiling all `style.scss` files into `./assets/css/style.blocks.css` and all `editor.scss` files into `./assets/css/editor.blocks.css` it seems to grab the SASS from the LAST block folder only (`./blocks/block3').

This indicates that `style.blocks.css` and `editor.blocks.css` are continuously being overwritten which is incorrect. I think the loader that writes the final two CSS files may need to be a plugin instead? I've tried the MiniCssExtractPlugin but couldn't get that to output two CSS files based on multiple SASS files.

Here's the full repo: https://github.com/dgwyer/multiple-webpack-css-files

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working in webpack 4 with the MiniCssExtractPlugin webpack plugin, with a minor workaround which shouldn't be necessary in webpack 5 apparently.

https://github.com/dgwyer/multiple-webpack-css-files